# How do i structure Selenium Framework for multiple country of single application?

Tags: selenium, automation, frameworks

I have an application to automate through Selenium - Page object model (POM), That application works on 12 countries (different urls), so how do i structure my framework, will POM be a hit in this case ?
All the 12 countries differs in locators  but the test cases remains same across countries.

Comment: You need to add more details. An example use case and how it varies among the countries would be a good place to start...

Comment: With "pom" do you mean Page object model (I guess so) or Maven's pom.xml? If the f former, page remove the pom.xml tag.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't use `linkText`, `partialLinkText`, or XPath and CssSelectors that rely on the text of the elements, then your tests should be language agnostic.